# Parsing Gaussian09 frequency calculations, reformatting depending on desired output

Tags: parsing, bash

Quite similar to [my earlier review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/129854/92423) this script parses a frequency calculation and reformats the found values to either fit into one row for easier importing into a spreadsheet software or a formatted table.

The whole project including sample calculation files for testing can be found [on github](https://github.com/polyluxus/tools-for-g09/tree/add-getfreq). I checked the script with http://www.shellcheck.net/# and there were no warnings left. I am looking for some input, whether I could simplify some of the code or make it more efficient.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script can be used to parse one (or more) frequency calculation(s)
# of the quantum chemical software suite Gaussian09

# Intitialise scriptoptions
errCount=0
printlevel=0
isOptimisation=0
isFreqCalc=0
ignorePrintlevelSwitch=0

# Initialise all variables that are of interest
declare filename functional temperature pressure 
declare electronicEnergy zeroPointEnergy thermalCorrEnergy thermalCorrEnthalpy thermalCorrGibbs
declare -a contributionNames thermalE heatCapacity entropy
declare routeSection

# Errors, Info and Warnings
fatal ()
{
    echo "ERROR  : " "$@"
    exit 1
}

message ()
{
    echo "INFO   : " "$@"
}

warn ()
{
    echo "WARNING: " "$@"
} 

# Parse the commands that have been passed to Gaussian09
getRouteSec ()
{
    # The route section is echoed in the log file, but it might spread over various lines
    # options might be cut off in the middle. It always starts with # folowed by a space
    # or the various verbosity levels NPT (case insensitive). The route section is 
    # terminated by a line of dahes. The script will stop reading the file if encountered.
    local line appendline 
    local addline=0
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*#[nNpPtT]?[[:space:]] || "$addline" == "1" ]]; then
            [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*[-]+[[:space:]]*$ ]] && break
            appendline="$appendline$line"
            addline=1
        fi
    done < "$filename" 

    routeSection="$appendline"
}

# Test the route section if it is an optimisation or frequency calculation (or both)
testRouteSec ()
{
    local testRouteSection="$1"
    if [[ $testRouteSection =~ ([oO][pP][tT][^[:space:]]*)([[:space:]]|$) ]]; then
        warn "This appears to be an optimisation."
        warn "Found '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}' in the route section."
        warn "The script is not intended for creating a summary of an optimisation."
        isOptimisation=1
    fi
    if [[ $testRouteSection =~ ([Ff][Rr][Ee][Qq][^[:space:]]*)([[:space:]]|$) ]]; then
        message "Found '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}' in the route section."
        isFreqCalc=1
    fi
}

# Print the route section in human readable form
printRouteSec ()
{
    message "Found route section:"
    fold -w80 -c -s < <(echo "$routeSection")
    echo "----"
}

getElecEnergy ()
{
    # The last value is the only of concern. Since the script is intended for single
    # point calculations, it is expected that the energy is printed early in the file.
    # It will not fail if it is an optimisation (warning printed earlier).
    local -r readWholeLine=$(grep -e 'SCF Done' "$filename" | tail -n 1)
    # Gaussian output has following format, trap important information:
    # Method, electronic Energy
    # Example taken from BP86/cc-pVTZ for water (H2O): 
    #  SCF Done:  E(RB-P86) =  -76.4006006969     A.U. after   10 cycles
    local pattern="E\((.+)\) =[[:space:]]+([-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[[:space:]]+A\.U\..+ cycles"
    if [[ $readWholeLine =~ $pattern ]]; then
        functional="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        electronicEnergy="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# Get the desired information from the thermochemistry block
# parse the lines according to keywords and trap the values.

findTempPress ()
{
    local readWholeLine="$1"
    local pattern
    pattern="^Temperature[[:space:]]+ ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[[:space:]]+Kelvin\.[[:space:]]+Pressure[[:space:]]+ ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[[:space:]]+Atm\.$"
    if [[ $readWholeLine =~ $pattern ]]; then
        temperature="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        pressure="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

findZeroPointEnergy ()
{
    local readWholeLine="$1"
    local pattern
    pattern="Zero-point correction=[[:space:]]+([-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
    if [[ $readWholeLine =~ $pattern ]]; then
        zeroPointEnergy="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

findThermalCorrEnergy ()
{
    local readWholeLine="$1"
    local pattern
    pattern="Thermal correction to Energy=[[:space:]]+([-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
    if [[ $readWholeLine =~ $pattern ]]; then
        thermalCorrEnergy="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

findThermalCorrEnthalpy ()
{
    local readWholeLine="$1"
    local pattern
    pattern="Thermal correction to Enthalpy=[[:space:]]+([-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
    if [[ $readWholeLine =~ $pattern ]]; then
        thermalCorrEnthalpy="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

findThermalCorrGibbs ()
{
    local readWholeLine="$1"
    local pattern
    pattern="Thermal correction to Gibbs Free Energy=[[:space:]]+([-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
    if [[ $readWholeLine =~ $pattern ]]; then
        thermalCorrGibbs="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# In the entropy block the given table needs to be transposed.
# Heat capacity and the break up of the internal energy are usually not that important,
# but they come as a freebie.
getEntropy ()
{
     local index=0
     while read -r line; do
         if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*E[[:space:]]{1}\(Thermal\)[[:space:]]+CV[[:space:]]+S[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
             continue
         fi
         if [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*KCal/Mol[[:space:]]+Cal/Mol-Kelvin[[:space:]]+Cal/Mol-Kelvin[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
             continue
         fi
         numpattern="[-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
         pattern="^[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z]+)[[:space:]]+($numpattern)[[:space:]]+($numpattern)[[:space:]]+($numpattern)[[:space:]]*+$"
         if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
             contributionNames[$index]=${BASH_REMATCH[1]:0:3}
             thermalE[$index]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
             heatCapacity[$index]=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
             entropy[$index]=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
             (( index++ ))
         fi
     done < <(grep -A6 -e 'E (Thermal)[[:space:]]\+CV[[:space:]]\+S' "$filename")
}

# If requested print the transposed table of entropies, heat capacities and the break up of the int. energy.
printEntropy ()
{
     local index
     printf "%-15s : " "Contrib."
     for (( index=0; index < ${#contributionNames[@]}; index++ )); do
         printf "%-10s " "${contributionNames[$index]}"
     done 
     printf "%-15s\n" "Unit"
     printf "%-11s %4s: " "thermal en." "(U)"
     for (( index=0; index < ${#thermalE[@]}; index++ )); do
         printf "%+10.3f " "${thermalE[$index]}"
     done 
     printf "%-15s\n" "kcal/mol"
     printf "%-11s %4s: " "heat cap." "(Cv)"
     for (( index=0; index < ${#heatCapacity[@]}; index++ )); do
         printf "%+10.3f " "${heatCapacity[$index]}"
     done 
     printf "%-15s\n" "cal/(mol K)"
     printf "%-11s %4s: " "entropy" "(S)"
     for (( index=0; index < ${#entropy[@]}; index++ )); do
         printf "%+10.3f " "${entropy[$index]}"
     done 
     printf "%-15s\n" "cal/(mol K)"

}

# Grep should be faster than parsing every line of the outputfile with =~
getThermochemistryLines ()
{
    grep -e 'Temperature.*Pressure' -e 'Zero-point correction' \
         -e 'Thermal correction to Energy' -e 'Thermal correction to Enthalpy' \
         -e 'Thermal correction to Gibbs Free Energy' \
         "$filename"
}

# Parse the thermochemistry output
getThermochemistry ()
{
    while read -r line; do
        findTempPress           "$line"  && continue
        findZeroPointEnergy     "$line"  && continue
        findThermalCorrEnergy   "$line"  && continue
        findThermalCorrEnthalpy "$line"  && continue
        findThermalCorrGibbs    "$line"  && continue
    done < <(getThermochemistryLines "$filename")
}

getAllEnergies ()
{
    getElecEnergy || fatal "Unable to find electronic energy."
    (( isFreqCalc == 1 )) && getThermochemistry
    (( isFreqCalc == 1 )) && getEntropy
}

# If only one line of output is requested for easier importing
printAllEnergiesInline ()
{
    local fs="$1"
    local index
    local header=("Method" "T (K)" "P (atm)" "E(SCF) (au/p)" \
                  "E(ZPE) (au/p)" "U(corr) (au/p)" "H(corr) (au/p)" "G(corr) (au/p)" \
                  "S (cal/[mol K])" "Cv (cal/[mol K])")
    local values=("$functional" "$temperature" "$pressure" "$electronicEnergy" \
                  "$zeroPointEnergy" "$thermalCorrEnergy" "$thermalCorrEnthalpy" "$thermalCorrGibbs"\
                  "${entropy[0]}" "${heatCapacity[0]}")
    local printHeader printValues

    for (( index=0; index < ${#header[@]}; index++ )); do
        if [ ${#values[$index]} -lt ${#header[$index]} ]; then
            printf -v printHeader "%s%-*s%s" "$printHeader" ${#header[$index]} "${header[$index]}" "$fs"
            printf -v printValues "%s%*s%s"  "$printValues" ${#header[$index]} "${values[$index]}" "$fs"
        else                                                                  
            printf -v printHeader "%s%-*s%s" "$printHeader" ${#values[$index]} "${header[$index]}" "$fs"
            printf -v printValues "%s%*s%s"  "$printValues" ${#values[$index]} "${values[$index]}" "$fs"
        fi
    done

    message "File: $filename"
    echo "$printHeader"
    echo "$printValues"
}

# Print a table (e.g. for archiving)
printAllEnergiesTable ()
{
     printf "%-25s %8s: %-20s %-20s\n"    "calculation details"   ""        "$functional"          "$filename" 
     printf "%-25s %8s: %20.3f %-20s\n"   "temperature"           "(T)"     "$temperature"         "K"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %20.5f %-20s\n"   "pressure"              "(p)"     "$pressure"            "atm"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.10f %-20s\n" "electr. en."           "(E)"     "$electronicEnergy"    "hartree"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.6f %-20s\n"  "zero-point corr."      "(ZPE)"   "$zeroPointEnergy"     "hartree/particle"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.6f %-20s\n"  "thermal corr."         "(U)"     "$thermalCorrEnergy"   "hartree/particle"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.6f %-20s\n"  "ther. corr. enthalpy"  "(H)"     "$thermalCorrEnthalpy" "hartree/particle"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.6f %-20s\n"  "ther. corr. Gibbs en." "(G)"     "$thermalCorrGibbs"    "hartree/particle"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.3f %-20s\n"  "entropy (total)"       "(S tot)" "${entropy[0]}"        "cal/(mol K)"
     printf "%-25s %8s: %+20.3f %-20s\n"  "heat capacity (total)" "(Cv t)"  "${heatCapacity[0]}"   "cal/(mol K)"
}

printSummary ()
{ 
     case $printlevel in
         0) printAllEnergiesInline " ";;
         c) printAllEnergiesInline ", ";;
         1) printAllEnergiesTable ;;
         2) printRouteSec 
            printAllEnergiesTable ;;
         3) printRouteSec
            printAllEnergiesTable
            printf "%s\nDetails of the composition\n" "----"
            printEntropy ;;
         *) fatal "Unrecognised printlevel: $printlevel"
     esac

     # All variable should be unset in case another file is processed
     unset filename functional temperature pressure 
     unset electronicEnergy zeroPointEnergy thermalCorrEnergy thermalCorrEnthalpy thermalCorrGibbs
     unset contributionNames thermalE heatCapacity entropy
     unset routeSection
}

analyseLog ()
{
    getRouteSec 
    testRouteSec "$routeSection"
    getAllEnergies
    if [[ $isFreqCalc == "1" ]]; then
        printSummary
        unset isFreqCalc isOptimisation
    else
        (( isOptimisation == 1 )) && local append=" (last value)"
        message "$filename"
        message "Electronic energy$append: $electronicEnergy hartree"
        unset isOptimisation electronicEnergy routeSection
    fi
}

# Start main script

# Evaluate options
while getopts :vcV:hu options ; do
    case $options in
        v) [[ $ignorePrintlevelSwitch == 1 ]] || ((printlevel++)) ;;
        c) printlevel="c" ;;
        V) if [[ $OPTARG =~ ^[0-9]{1}$ ]]; then
               printlevel="$OPTARG" 
               ignorePrintlevelSwitch=1
           else
               fatal "Invalid argument: $OPTARG"
           fi ;;
        # The following will be substituted by a proper help
        h) message "Usage: $0 [options] filenames(s)"; exit 0 ;;
        # The following will be substituted by a proper usage guidance
        u) message "Usage: $0 [options] filenames(s)"; exit 0 ;;
       \?) warn "Invalid option: -$OPTARG." ;;
        :) fatal "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

# Check if filename is specified
if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then 
    fatal "No output file specified. Nothing to do."
fi

# Assume all other commandline arguments are filenames
while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
    filename="$1"
    if [ ! -e "$filename" ]; then 
        warn "Specified logfile '$filename' does not exist. Continue."
        ((errCount++))
    else
        analyseLog "$filename"
    fi
    shift
    [[ ! -z "$1" && $printlevel -gt 0 ]] && echo "===="
done

# Issue an error if files have not been found.
if [ "$errCount" -gt 0 ]; then
    fatal "There have been one or more errors reading the specified files."
fi
```

Comment: I'm curious about why you chose to do this in Bash.

Comment: @200_success Unfortunately I never learned a real programming language, it's just the bits and pieces my former admin thought me during my PhD. I'm positive there are more elegant and efficient languages, but it's the only thing I know how to get the job done. And I still have a lot more quick and dirty scripts.

Comment: I'm amused and impressed, since I think it's actually harder to do this kind of work in Bash than in a real programming language. If you want to specialize in Bash, I suggest that you at least learn `awk` well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use a for-each loop when the index is not needed

In this loop you don't really need the loop index:

> ```
>  for (( index=0; index < ${#contributionNames[@]}; index++ )); do
>      printf "%-10s " "${contributionNames[$index]}"
>  done
> ```

Since you need just the elements, a for-each loop is more natural:

```
 for name in "${contributionNames[@]}"; do
     printf "%-10s " "$name"
 done
```

Do the same for the other counting loops too where possible.

#### Use here-string instead of redirecting `echo`

Instead of this:

> ```
> fold -w80 -c -s < <(echo "$routeSection")
> ```

Better to use a here-string to avoid an additional process creation:

```
fold -w80 -c -s <<< "$routeSection"
```

#### Use modern `(( ... ))` consistently

Since you used `(( ... ))` a lot, I don't understand why you didn't use it here:

> ```
>     if [ ${#values[$index]} -lt ${#header[$index]} ]; then
> ```

`-lt` is old-fashioned, you could use naturally `<` in a `(( ... ))`.

A consistent writing style improves readability.

#### Simple scripts evolving into complex programs

This script is getting really complex. Bash is great for simple things, but when things start to get complex, it often becomes a wrestle. I would recommend Python as a scripting language for complex tasks. It has great unit testing facilities too.

Comment: Thank you as always for your comments. Bash is currently the only thing I know well enough to get me started, but I have considered learning a bit more. Since you are recommending python, do you also have a recommendation for a starter guide or tutorial?

Comment: Absolutely, I recommend the official tutorial, it's great, and a good way to start out on the right foot, following good *pythonic* practices https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/